# Number of Positive Definite Binary Matrices

Tags: boolean-algebra, binary

How may positive definite matrices (over finite field- $F_p$) are possible? What is the criterion in getting those?

Comment: Since finite fields are not ordered, it's hard to know what you mean.  The subject line talks about "binary matrices" but the Question asks about "over finite field - $F_p$", so you need to be more exact.

Comment: What is the definition of a positive definite matrix over a finite field? What is the scalar product you are using (a scalar product is integral to the definition of positive definite matrices)?

Comment: As an example, I mean the entries of the matrix are either 0 or 1. The standard positive definition works.

Comment: I am mainly interested in binary matrices, but the general problem is much interesting!

Comment: The "standard definition" says a symmetric matrix is positive definite if something is **positive** . We don't have, as far as I am aware of, a notion of *positive* in finite fields (or, for that matter, in fields of positive characteristic)

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is counting the binary matrices $M$ (all entries zero or one) that are positive definite *symmetric* as real matrices, the answer seems to be only the $n \times n$ identity matrix for each $n$.

Certainly the diagonal must consist of ones, else $e_i^T M e_i$ would be zero for some standard basis vector $e_i$.

If some off-diagonal matrix entry is $1$, then we have a singular $2\times 2$ principal minor, thus disproving the [positive definiteness](http://www.math.wsu.edu/faculty/tsat/files/pcon_c.pdf) of $M$.

If the problem involves counting matrices over a finite field, there is no "standard definition that works" of positive definite matrix.  Indeed there is no notion of positive that works in a finite field, since for characteristic $p$ one gets:

$$ 1 + 1 + \ldots + 1 = 0 $$

for $p$ copies of summand $1$, so while $1 = 1^2$ ought to be "positive", it isn't (by the definition used for [ordered fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_field)).